# New web service host 0.0.0.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, host

Can anyone tell me why when I create a new web service in an asp.net project does it tell me that the host is 0.0.0.0? This is also disallowing me to test the webservice because its coming from a different IP than the host (obviously not 0.0.0.0). What the hell is going on? What did I configure wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

Is this your own web service?

The location of the web service is in the code. 
Above your service class, you should see something like this

[WebService(Namespace = "http://yourserver:yourport/")]

Make sure that it points to the right location - assuming that your service is deployed to a server.

Either way, in the client project, point your web reference to the right location and refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, 0.0.0.0 means it is bound to all the IP addresses on the host. I'm not sure why that would be causing a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen before: an ASP.NET web service which redirects to 0.0.0.0 whenever a method is invoked either by using the ASP.NET web form, SOAPUI or any client for that matter.

I recommend you try reinstalling asp.net (in command prompt, by using aspnet_regiis -u to uninstall, and aspnet_regiis -i to reinstall) and/or rebooting the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer to this (at least for me - 64bit Vista). Edit hosts and comment out the line ::1 localhost

i.e.

```
#::1             localhost
```

then reboot.